# setATRHistBytes() method always returns false

Tags: smartcard, javacard, globalplatform

I wrote the following program to change the *Historical Bytes* in the ATR of my smartcard to, for example, `0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00`. I use `GPSystem.setATRHistBytes()` to set the historical bytes.

Note that `0x00 0x00 ... 0x00` is not the actual value that I'm using for the historical bytes but I censored it. The actual value is an array of 15 bytes that is equal to the historical bytes of another exisitng card.

```
package org.globalplatform;

import javacard.framework.*;
import org.globalplatform.GPSystem;

public class TestPrj extends Applet {

    public static final byte[] HIST_B= {(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00};
    public static byte counter = (byte) 0x00;

    public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) {
        new TestPrj();
    }

    protected TestPrj() {
        register();
    }

    public void process(APDU apdu) {

        if (selectingApplet()) {
            if (counter == 0x03) {
                counter = (byte) (counter + 1);
                boolean changed = GPSystem.setATRHistBytes(HIST_B, (short) 0, (byte) HIST_B.length);
                if (changed) {
                    ISOException.throwIt((short) 0x9000);
                } else {
                    ISOException.throwIt((short) 0x6400);
                }

            } else {
                counter = (byte) (counter + 1);
            }
        }

        ISOException.throwIt((short) counter);
    }
}
```

After converting the above program to its CAP file and installing the applet with `Default Selected` privilege (which is required to use `GPSystem.setATRHistBytes()`), I still have problems with changing the historical bytes.

Based on the APDU responses that I receive, it seems that the `setATRHistBytes()` method always returns `false` indicating the the historical bytes are not updated.

```
Connect successful.
Download Cap begin...
Download Cap successful.
Install Applet begin...
Install Applet successful.
Send: 00 A4 04 00 06 01 02 03 04 05 01
Recv: 00 01
Time used: 22.000 ms
Send: 00 A4 04 00 06 01 02 03 04 05 01
Recv: 00 02
Time used: 23.000 ms
Send: 00 A4 04 00 06 01 02 03 04 05 01
Recv: 00 03
Time used: 24.000 ms
Send: 00 A4 04 00 06 01 02 03 04 05 01
Recv: 64 00
Time used: 15.000 ms
Send: 00 A4 04 00 06 01 02 03 04 05 01
Recv: 00 05
Time used: 15.000 ms
```

Note that `01 02 03 04 05 01` is my applet AID.

My card is JCOP v2.4.2 R3 and I tried to compile against both GP 2.2.1 v1.6 and GP 2.2 v1.4 APIs.

Comment: Do your historical bytes follow structure rules? See http://www.cardwerk.com/smartcards/smartcard_standard_ISO7816-4_8_historical_bytes.aspx. I am not sure if that could help you, but it is definitely worth trying, I hope...

Comment: @vojta As I did a copy&paste from historical bytes of another card in the `HIST_B` field, can I conclude that I followed the structure rules? (`0x00 0x00 .... 0x00` is not the real value that I want to set. I censored it. Actually it is a 15 bytes array.)

Comment: @vojta loading a wrong version globalPlatform `.java` files in my package can cause this issue? (for example loading GP 2.2 version 1.3 `.java` API files instead of GP 2.2 version 1.1 `.java` API files)

Comment: What implementation of API do you use? What is your card type?

Comment: @vojta My card is  **JCOP v2.4.2 r3** and I tried both _GP 2.2.1 v1.6_ and _GP 2.2 v1.4_ APIs.

Comment: Could you try to replace `public static final byte[] HIST_B =` with `public final byte[] HIST_B =`?

Comment: A global array must be passed to `setATRHistBytes()`. Try copying the contents of `HIST_B` into the APDU buffer (which is the only global aray available during the invokation of the process method) and then pass the APDU buffer into `setATRHistBytes()`.

Comment: @vlp I tried it, but nothing changed. Tnx.

Comment: @MichaelRoland Yes, this is the solution. Thank you. Please post your comment as an answer and let me check it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setATRHistBytes(byte[] baBuffer, short sOffset, byte bLength)` requires a global array passed as input buffer (`baBuffer`). See the [API documentation](http://www.win.tue.nl/pinpasjc/docs/apis/gp211/org/globalplatform/GPSystem.html#setATRHistBytes%28byte[],%20short,%20byte%29):

> `baBuffer` - the source byte array containing the ATR historical bytes. **Must be a global array.**

A global array is a special array that is managed by the Java Card runtime and accessible by all applets. During the invokation of the `process()` applet lifecylce method, the only global buffer that you can expect to be available to your Java Card applet is the APDU buffer.

Therefore, you need to copy the contents of `HIST_B` into the APDU buffer and then pass the APDU buffer into `setATRHistBytes()`:

```
byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(HIST_B, (short)0, buffer, (short)0, (short)HIST_B.length);
boolean changed = GPSystem.setATRHistBytes(buffer, (short)0, (short)HIST_B.length);
```

Comment: Thank you Mr Roland. I think this method (`setATRHistBytes()`) can only change the Cold Reset ATR. Is there any method to change the Warm Reset ATR too?

Comment: And another question: When I delete my Applet, the ATR become its previous value or it is fixed to this new value that I configured?

Comment: Well, I tried it. For my card (**JCOP V2.4.2 R3**) deleting the applet, cause  the CM to revoke the previous ATR.