# JAVACARD possible to change ATQB response

Tags: javacard

I am using JC30M48CR Type B Javacard and JCIDE for compiling.

I searched for the whole forum to find out if it is possible to change ATQB response for JAVACARD. However, all topics are about change ATR as given in [setATRHistBytes() method always returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34390973/setatrhistbytes-method-always-returns-false).

May I know whether it is possible to customise ATQB? For example, the request code for ISO14443B is 05 00 00, then the ATQB response is 50 00 00 00 00 D1 03 86 0C 00 80 80.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because Java Card does not control the lower level protocols at that level. And actually, the historical bytes are not applicable to Type B cards; you'd need to have an ATR specific file in the root folder to be able to communicate the historical bytes, because they are simply not present in the ISO/IEC 14443 type B protocol.

If the communication parameters can be set then that specific functionality is OS specific. So in general - if you're big enough - then you can have chips delivered with special settings. You may also be able to set the parameters yourself through another OS provided initialization application on chip. Those are all vendor specific.

Of course the vendors do not want to let any applet change the communication parameters. For the historical bytes the Java Card Forum compromised on only allow the default selected applet change the historical bytes (instead of using a specific INSTALL for INSTALL flag or other authentication measures).

In short: contact your supplier and ask for the user manual.

Comment: Hi Maarten, Thanks for your useful suggestion. I will contact the supplier to confirm.. Thanks